# Execution after closure property

Tags: groovy, closures, dsl

I want to execute code right after                                                                                                       branching to a closure like this:

```
def run(String s) {
    println "run ${s}"
    ["then": { input ->
        println "then ${input}"
    }]
    //println "Done"
}

run "123" then "456"
```

This works as expected but what if I want to run some code right after the closure?

F.i. if I uncomment the line `println "Done"` I get a **NullPointerException**.

I kind of understand why this happens, is there a way to do it though?

**Edit**
Thanks to cfrick this is what I wanted to do, it works now;

```
result = ["then": { input...
// Do my stuff here
return result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's disect this a little bit and write this more explicit:

```
def run(String s) {
    println "run ${s}"
    return ["then": { input -> println "then ${input}" }]
}

run("123").then("456")
```

So if we uncomment that `println`, this changes to:

```
def run(String s) {
    println "run ${s}"
    // this now is just a no-op
    ["then": { input -> println "then ${input}" }]
    return println("Done")
}
```

You get the NPE because null is the return value of `println`.

So at this point it's unclear, what you really want here.  If you want
to print the "Done" as part of the run, just print it before (but then
it's just the same as `println "run...` right now.  Or you put it
inside the closure, but then it's just the same as the `println
"then...`.

So I assume you want to chain those calls.  In that case each closure
must return something to chain with.  E.g.

```
def run(String s) {
    println "run ${s}"
    return [then: { 
        println "then ${it}"
        return [done: { println "done $it" }]
    }]
}

run "123" then "456" done "789"
```